# Set variable over a variable in a function

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to change every value of a variable with a specific function

For that I tried this:

```
 Value = 0

 def ChangeValue(Variable):
     Variable = 1

 ChangeValue(Value)

 print(Value)
```

It actually should outcome 1, but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Variable` inside of `ChangeValue()` is its own "box" with its own value. When you pass `Value` to `ChangeValue()`, you take the value from `Value` and put it in `Variable`. Changing the value of `Variable` does not affect the value of `Value`. This is what many languages call pass-by-value.

Comment: Okay, and how can I change it over the function ?

Comment: @Alex To answer that, I need more detail about what you are really trying to do. I appreciate that you made your original example simple. However, you seem to have simplified too far and left out some important details.

Comment: @Alex What I am trying to say is that changing a variable in the way you want is not allowed in Python. There is probably some different solution to your original problem that will work.

Comment: Okay, thats enough I need to know